# Polynomial fit matlab with some constraints on the coefficients

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have data that I should interpolate with a function which must be of the following kind:

> `f(x) = ax4 + bx2 + c`

with `a > 0` and `b ≤ 0`. Unfortunately, MATLAB's [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) does not allow any constraints on the coefficients of the polynomial. Does anybody know if there is a MATLAB function to do this? Otherwise, how can I implement it?

Thank you very much in advance,

Elisabetta

Comment: why `a>0` and not `a>=0`? suppose your optimization results with `a=0`, then setting it to `a=\epsilon` would change very little...

Comment: Yes, you're right, I said a>0 just because my data never "behave" like a function with a closed to 0, but I don't necessarily have to set it as a constraint

Comment: @bettaberg: I'm still anxious to know where those constraints come from...? What are you trying to model, and why the constraints on the parameters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try using `fminsearch`, `fminunc` defining your objective function manually.

Alternatively, you can define your problem slightly different:

> `f(x) = a2x4 - b2x2 + c`

Now, the new `a` and `b` can be optimized for **without** constraints, while ensuring that the final `a` and `b` you are looking for are positive (negative resp.).

Answer (score 7):

Without constraints, the problem can be written and solved as a simple linear system:

```
% Your design matrix ([4 2 0] are the powers of the polynomial)
A = bsxfun(@power, your_X_data(:), [4 2 0]);

% Best estimate for the coefficients, [a b c], found by 
% solving A*[a b c]' = y in a least-squares sense
abc = A\your_Y_data(:)
```

Those constraints will of course automatically be satisfied **iff** that constrained model indeed underlies your data. For example,

```
% some example factors
a = +23.9;
b = -15.75;
c = 4;

% Your model
f = @(x, F) F(1)*x.^4 + F(2)*x.^2 + F(3);

% generate some noisy XY data
x = -1:0.01:1;
y = f(x, [a b c]) + randn(size(x));

% Best unconstrained estimate a, b and c from the data
A = bsxfun(@power, x(:), [4 2 0]);
abc = A\y(:);

% Plot results
plot(x,y, 'b'), hold on
plot(x, f(x, abc), 'r')
xlabel('x (nodes)'), ylabel('y (data)')
```

[image]

However, if you impose constraints on data that are *not* accurately described by that constrained model, things might go wrong:

```
% Note: same data, but flipped signs 
a = -23.9;
b = +15.75;
c = 4;

f = @(x, F) F(1)*x.^4 + F(2)*x.^2 + F(3);

% generate some noisy XY data
x = -1:0.01:1;
y = f(x, [a b c]) + randn(size(x));

% Estimate a, b and c from the data, Forcing a>0 and b<0
abc = fmincon(@(Y) sum((f(x,Y)-y).^2), [0 0 0], [-1 0 0; 0 +1 0; 0 0 0], zeros(3,1));

% Plot results
plot(x,y, 'b'), hold on
plot(x, f(x, abc), 'r')
xlabel('x (nodes)'), ylabel('y (data)')
```

[image]

(this solution has `a == 0`, indicative of an incorrect model choice).

If the exact equality of `a == 0` is a problem: there is of course no difference if you set `a == eps(0)`. Numerically, this will not be noticeable for real-world data, but it's nonzero nonetheless.

Anyway, I have a suspicion that your model is not well chosen and the constraints are a "fix" to get everything to work, or your data should actually be unbiased/rescaled before trying to make any fit, or that some similar preconditions apply (I've often seen people do this sort of thing, so yes, I'm a bit biased in this respect :).

So...what are the real reasons behind those constraints?

Comment: it's a bit naive to say "since we assumed this model, the constraints should be automatically satisfied by the data"...

Comment: @Shai: where exactly did I say that? There was a pretty explicit ***IF*** there...

Comment: I probably should have rephrased my comment differently, but the point is: if you have constraints on your parameters you should use them and not hope that they will be miraculasly satisfied...

Comment: Most importantly: +1 for a detailed solution.

Comment: Yes, I understand :) well, actually I'm not an expert Matlab user and the only way I found to find the best fit for a polynomial function was polyfit, which does not even allow to set the coefficients of x and x^3 to 0.. the fact that a is >0 and b<=0 effectively comes directly from my data so I don't necessarily have to set it as a constraint, I guess.. Sorry if I formulated my question in a rather ambiguous way and thank you for your help, now everything is clear! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have the curve fitting toolbox then [fit](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) does allow for setting constraints using the 'upper' and 'lower' options. You would want something like.

```
M=fit(x, f, 'poly4', 'upper', [-inf, 0, -inf, 0, -inf], 'lower', [0, 0, 0, 0, -inf]);
```

Note use -inf to set a particular coefficient to be unconstrained.

This will give a cfit object with the relevant coefficients. You can access these using for example M.p1 for the x^4 term. Alternatively you can evaluate the function at whatever points you want using [feval](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/feval.html).

I think you can do a similar thing using lsqcurvefit in the optimization toolbox as well.

Comment: This is the quickest and simplest way to do it